# Dual pairing on $H^1_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimal-control

I am reading an article on optimal control by [Jean-Pierre RAYMOND](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~raymond/book-ficus.pdf) and on page 57, in the proof of Theorem 5.4.4 he uses the fact that

$\int_{\Omega} |\nabla((-\Delta)^{-1}f)|^2=\langle f,(-\Delta)^{-1}f\rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1_0} $

The only way I can explain this to myself is by the following argument : If we take the norm $\|g\|_{H^1}=\int_\Omega|\nabla g|^2$ on $H^1$, then because of the Riesz representation theorem, for every $f\in H^{-1}$ there exists a $u_f\in H_0^1$ such that

$\langle f,g\rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1_0}=\int_\Omega \nabla g\nabla u_f$

for every $g\in H_0^1$. Now we can identify $u_f$ by the isomorphism $(-\Delta)^{-1}:H^{-1}\rightarrow H^1_0$ and we finally get

$\langle f,g\rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1_0}=\int_\Omega \nabla g\nabla (-\Delta)^{-1}f$.

By replacing $g$ with the term above yields the result. I'm not quite sure if this correct though, some help would be appreciated

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea. Let's introduce $g=(-\Delta)^{-1}f$, so that the claim becomes more readable: 
$$\int_{\Omega} |\nabla g|^2=\langle -\Delta g,g \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1_0}\tag1$$ 
Recall the general definition of  $-\Delta g$: it is the distribution $T$ that acts on test functions $\varphi$ by 
$$ T(\varphi) =  -\int g\Delta \varphi\tag2$$
When $g\in H^1$, we can integrate by parts on the right, obtaining another formula for $T$: 
$$ T(\varphi) =   \int \nabla g \nabla \varphi\tag3$$
The right hand  side of (3) is a continuous linear functional on $ H^1_0$, and therefore $T$ extends to an element of $H^{-1}$. Computing $T(g)$ according to (3), we get (1).

Comment: Yes, substituting with $g$ makes the argument a lot simpler, thanks a lot for your help